# sql separate one field into columns depending on value of initial field

Tags: sql

I am trying to separate one field in one table, into two columns in a report, populating each column depending on the value of that initial field. Here is how the tables are structured. TABLES VIEW I am quite new to sql, and am learning slowly, but have tried cases, and sub-queries, but no luck... I do hope some kind sole will be able to help me. :P

My database is structured like this:

[image]

This is the query I am using

```
SELECT 
  Insurance_Folder.code, Rating_Section.rating_section_type_id, Rating_Section.sum_insured, Rating_Section_Type.description
FROM
  dbo.Rating_Section
Left Outer Join dbo.Rating_Section_Type ON 
  Rating_Section.rating_section_type_id = Rating_Section_Type.rating_section_type_id
Left Outer Join dbo.Insurance_Folder
Left Outer Join dbo.Insurance_File ON 
  Insurance_Folder.insurance_folder_cnt = Insurance_File.insurance_folder_cnt
Left Outer Join dbo.insurance_file_risk_link ON 
  Insurance_File.insurance_file_cnt = insurance_file_risk_link.insurance_file_cnt and insurance_file_risk_link.risk_cnt = Rating_Section.risk_cnt
WHERE
  Rating_Section.rating_section_type_id = 219 or Rating_Section.rating_section_type_id = 228
```

This gives me the following result ( I can not post another image)
-All the codes from Insurance folder, with each rating section type for each code, on a row. I want to separate the row with second value, and have it put in the same row of the code, in a separate column, depending on the value of rating_section_type_id

And these are the results I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  SQL Server and MySQL are quite different.

Comment: Table aliases make SQL code much easier to write and to read, especially with those long table names.

Comment: You might simplify your question. There's a lot of content in here that isn't relevant (all the join tables). Are you trying to split the value in a single column into two columns? That's string manipulation. Or are you trying to join different values in a single column back to another table, depending on some other column (`rating_section_type_id`)? That's a join.